# set checkbox as checked/unchecked based on database jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to set data on `localStorage` as 1/0.Then if I get 1 from it I want to `checked` a checkbox else `unchecked`.I was wrote a code but it isn't working.And I can't find-out what I am doing wrong!

```
<label class="a-b-c">
  <input id="check-it" type="checkbox" name="check">
  Check.
</label>

$(window).load(set_func_o());
    function set_func_o(){
        try_it();
        $('#check-it').change(function(){
            var chk= this.checked ? '1':'0';
            localStorage.setItem('checkit-the-item',chk);
            try_it();
        });
        function try_it(){
        var check_stat= localStorage.getItem('checkit-the-item');
        check_stat === '1' ? $('#checkit').prop('checked',true):$('#checkit').prop('checked',false);
        }
    }
```

Suggestion please!

Comment: Take off the `()` on your load binding.  It should be `$(window).load(set_func_o);` so you are giving it a function reference, not invoking it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing a wrong element ID. Also, you can clean your code to only one prop setter.

```
function try_it(){
    var check_stat = localStorage.getItem('checkit-the-item');
    $('#check-it').prop('checked', check_stat === '1');
}
```

Comment: Exactly.  I've tried his code and the only thing preventing it from working was the wrong id.

Comment: How stupid I am :D . Thanks @F.Almeida for the clean code,it is much better.

Comment: I made a jquery extension that could be useful for you. Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/42gh5q27/